# Turning JSON user input with an unknown length into properly formatted html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to learn how to turn JSON content into HTML structures. In this project I am trying to create a menu for a restaurant that can be edited by a JSON file. The project is code-named "pike" to answer any questions about my variable naming.

What I am trying to do right now is have one JSON Array that holds an unknown amount of legend symbols (controlled by a user) and to turn that into html. The final product should look something like this:

> GF - GlutenFree, GFO - GlutenFree option, Veg - Vegitarian, V - Vegan

Where there could be any amount of legend symbols the user wants.

To start I have created a JSON array which assigns some html syntax to variables:

```
var syntax = {
"spanOpen": "<span>",
"spanClose": "</span>",
"hr": "<hr>",
"pike": {
    "menu": {
        "legendOpen": "<p class='legend'>",
        "legendClose": "</p>",
        "legendIndicatorOpen": "<span class='legend-indicator'>",
        "legendIndicatorClose": "</span>"
    }
} 
};
```

I have also created an array for user input that will be displayed in the menu:

```
var menuUserInput = {
"legend": [
    {
        "symbol": "GF",
        "description": "GlutenFree"
    }, {
        "symbol": "GFO",
        "description": "GlutenFree option"
    }, {
        "symbol": "Veg",
        "description": "Vegitarian"
    }, {
        "symbol": "V",
        "description": "Vegan"
    }
]
};
```

Then I created a variable to put the previous two together:

```
var menuResponsive = {
"legend": syntax.pike.menu.legendOpen + new Array(menuUserInput.legend.length + 1).join(syntax.spanOpen + menuUserInput.legend[0].symbol + syntax.spanClose + " - " + menuUserInput.legend[0].description + ", ") + syntax.pike.menu.legendClose,
};
```

The problem is that this produces the following:

> GF - GlutenFree, GF - GlutenFree, GF - GlutenFree, GF - GlutenFree,

And I have no clue how to get it to display correctly since I do not know how many legend items the user will want.

I have searched around a lot but unfortunately my knowledge in this realm is still very new. Thank you so much for anyone who takes the time to read this and help a noob out.

Comment: You're using `legend[0]` for everything. You need to write a loop or use `menuUserInput.legend.map()` to process all the elements.

Comment: what are expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over your `menuUserInput.legend` array items this way:

```js
var syntax = {
    "spanOpen": "<span>",
        "spanClose": "</span>",
        "hr": "<hr>",
        "pike": {
        "menu": {
             "legendOpen": "<p class='legend'>",
             "legendClose": "</p>",
             "legendIndicatorOpen": "<span class='legend-indicator'>",
             "legendIndicatorClose": "</span>",
            "legendIndicatorSpacer": " - "
        }
    }
};
var menuUserInput = {
    "legend": [{
        "symbol": "GF",
        "description": "GlutenFree",
    }, {
        "symbol": "GFO",
        "description": "GlutenFree option"
    }, {
        "symbol": "Veg",
        "description": "Vegitarian"
    }, {
        "symbol": "V",
        "description": "Vegan"
    }]
};
function createMenu(name) {
    var toReturn = '';
    if( typeof menuUserInput[name]!='undefined' ) {
        for(ind in menuUserInput[name]) {
          toReturn += syntax.pike.menu.legendOpen + syntax.pike.menu.legendIndicatorOpen + menuUserInput[name][ind].symbol + syntax.pike.menu.legendIndicatorClose + syntax.pike.menu.legendIndicatorSpacer + menuUserInput[name][ind].description + syntax.pike.menu.legendClose + '\n';  
        };
    };
    return toReturn;
};
var menuResponsive = createMenu('legend');
console.log( menuResponsive );
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = menuResponsive;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Also on **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfh9k9b9/)**.

Maybe you should read more about the [JSON structure](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: This answers so many questions and is really helpful to just look at and study! That link on JSON structure is a great resource too and the loop you wrote works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would rather "abstract" a little more the syntax object to avoid specifying opening and closing tags. Instead I would indicate what the type should be.

```js
/*
var syntax = {
   "spanOpen": "<span>",
   "spanClose": "</span>",
   "hr": "<hr>",
   "pike": {
     "menu": {
     "legendOpen": "<p class='legend'>",
     "legendClose": "</p>",
     "legendIndicatorOpen": "<span class='legend-indicator'>",
     "legendIndicatorClose": "</span>"
     }
   }
};
*/
var syntax2 = {
  
  groupItem:{
    type:'span',
    class:'pikeMenu'
   },
   divider:{
     type:'hr'
    },
    pike: {
      menu: {
        legendItem:{
          type:'p',
          class:'legend'
        },
        "legendIndicator":{
          type:'span',
          class:'legend-indicator'
        }
        
      }
      
    }
  
 };


var menuUserInput = {
  "legend": [
    {
      "symbol": "GF",
      "description": "GlutenFree"
    }, {
      "symbol": "GFO",
      "description": "GlutenFree option"
    }, {
      "symbol": "Veg",
      "description": "Vegitarian"
    }, {
      "symbol": "V",
      "description": "Vegan"
    }
  ]
};

window.onload = function () {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  /*
  var menuResponsive = {
    "legend": syntax.pike.menu.legendOpen +
    new Array(menuUserInput.legend.length + 1).join(syntax.spanOpen + menuUserInput.legend[0].symbol + syntax.spanClose + " - " + menuUserInput.legend[0].description + ", ") + syntax.pike.menu.legendClose
  };
  */

  //crete the container
  var groupContainer = document.createElement(syntax2.groupItem.type);
  groupContainer.textContent = "menu container";
  groupContainer.className = syntax2.groupItem.class;
  body.appendChild(groupContainer);
  var dividerItem = document.createElement(syntax2.divider.type);
  groupContainer.appendChild(dividerItem);

  for(var key in menuUserInput.legend){
    if(menuUserInput.legend.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      var legendItem = menuUserInput.legend[key];
      console.log(legendItem);
      var legendElement = document.createElement(syntax2.pike.menu.legendItem.type);
      legendElement.className = syntax2.pike.menu.legendItem.class;
      legendElement.textContent = legendItem.description;

      var legendIndicatorElement = document.createElement(syntax2.pike.menu.legendIndicator.type);
      legendIndicatorElement.className = syntax2.pike.menu.legendIndicator.class;
      legendIndicatorElement.textContent = legendItem.symbol;
      legendElement.appendChild(legendIndicatorElement);

      groupContainer.appendChild(legendElement);



    }
  }


}
```

```css
.pikeMenu{
            font-family: sans-serif;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid lightgrey;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .pikeMenu .legend{
            border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
            cursor: pointer;

        }
        .pikeMenu .legend:hover{
            background-color: azure;
        }
        .pikeMenu .legend .legend-indicator{
            float: left;
            color: lightblue;
        }
        .legend-indicator::after{
            display: inline-block;
            content: "-";
            margin-left: 4px;
            margin-right: 4px;
        }
```